# Why does every other object I create in a loop turns out blank on old version of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It's something that's really bothering me, and it's also kind of important since it's part of my job.
I made an object that basically parses a hostname and puts labels on the different parts of that name.
Sounds pretty straightforward, right? HOWEVER, when I create several instances of that object in a row, every other instance turns out blank, with nothing but _proto and a few functions. No data whatsoever.

It might be important to note that I'm using an old version of Chrome (which I have to use, since the network at work is closed-circuit and it's impossible to update the software beyond what's on the net). The same code works at home.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG, THEN?
Thanks in advance.

```
var reg = /([A,B,C,D,E])(\d{3})(\d{2})([F,G,H])(\d{2})/i;
var hostParser = function(hostname) {

    var parsed = reg.exec(hostname);
    if (parsed) {
        this.prefix = parsed[1];
        this.arena = parsed[2];
        this.waitingRoom = parsed[3];
        this.adminStatus = parsed[4];
        this.ID = parsed[5];
        this.hostname = hostname.toUpperCase();
        return this;
    }
    return false;
};
 Array.prototype.eliminateDuplicates = function() {
    var r = [];
    this.forEach(function(n) {
        if (r.indexOf(n) < 0)
            r.push(n);
    });
    return r;
};
Array.prototype.trim = function() {
    var r = [];
    this.forEach(function (n) {
        if (!/^\s?$/.test(n))
            r.push(n);
    });
    return r;
};
var list = [
    'A40800G01',
    'A40800G02',
    'A40800G03',
    'A40800G04',
    'A40800G05',
    'A40800G06',
    'A40800G07',
    'A40800G08',
    'A40800G09'
];
list.trim().eliminateDuplicates().forEach(function (item) {
    var itemParser = new hostParser(item);
    console.log(itemParser);
});
```

Comment: Did you try to log parsed variable inside hostParser and also item in forEach? What does it output?

Comment: It seems you are looking at a Chrome bug that is fixed in the latest version (as it apparently works as expected in the current version). What's the output of chrome://version on your machine (i.e. in which Chrome version does the bug occur)? With that you could try to search https://www.chromestatus.com for fixed bugs that sound similar to what you are experiencing...

Comment: Yes. It can go anywhere from an object {} consisting of nothing but prototype functions, to a mere 'undefined'.

Comment: @Dominik_Schreiber Thank you for your help! I'll be looking into it when I get to work tomorrow and post my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug with that particular Chrome version. Not being able to update, I duplicated array items on purpose and it worked.